# Getting values from text fields to pass to CLGeocoder

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I'm trying to display the latitude and longitude values of an address which the user has input into some text fields. I would ideally like the user to input the address, then click a button which will find the lat/lon and feed these values into two text fields in the same view. I'm just not sure how I call the address values of these text fields in my code.

Here's what I have so far

```
-(IBAction)getLatLon:(id)sender{

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init]; 
NSString *addressString = @"%@address, city, county, county, postcode";
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString inRegion:nil completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error)
 {
     for (CLPlacemark * aPlacemark in placemarks)
     {                    // Process the placemark.
         NSLog(@"Got Placemark : %@", aPlacemark);     

     }
 }];
```

}

It works when I hard code a value you in for example

```
NSString *addressString = @"Belfast";
```

I know I've probably tried to call the values in all wrong but my head is completely fried at this stage!

My Textfields are named as such

```
addressText.text
cityText.text
countyText.text
countryText.text
postcodeText.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of the [stringWithFormat:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) method.  Put in placeholders in your string (%@) for each *string* you want to use, and then list out the arguments after (are you familiar with `printf`?)

Comment: I've used it before I think! (to be honest I've been trying to create my app based on tutorials so far and haven't gotten round to learning objective-c yet.... Something I really regret!)

So Would it be something like this then?
NSString stringWithFormat *addressString = @"address %@ city %@ county %@ county %@ postcode %@";

Comment: Nope, not like that...You need your entire format string and THEN all of your arguments -> `@%"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@", addressText.text, cityText.text, countyText.text, countryText.text, postcodeText.text"`  Just like using variables.